Docker volume mount includes invalid characters: If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path
I am having trouble with two-way folders with Docker.
    defaultCfg.Mounts = append(ContainerHostConfig.Mounts, mount.Mount{
        Type:   mount.TypeVolume,
        Source: fmt.Sprintf("/root%s", tmp),
        Target: fmt.Sprintf("%s", tmp),
    })

Source and target works when using bind (with CreateMountpoint being true on bind config), but on volume i have this error:

"failed to create container: Error response from daemon: create /root/tmp/metrics-60-1990068486: "/root/tmp/metrics-60-1990068486" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path"


If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path

isnt this absolute?

/root/tmp/metrics-60-1990068486

what is wrong?

Mounting a directory is called a bind mount, so you need to use mount.TypeBind instead of mount.TypeVolume.

I tried that, but the bind target folder is not synchronized with the host folder. I need to access everything the container writes to that folder. *yes i set Propagation to shared there is still no synchronization between the folders

'Synchronization' implies that there are two directories. With a bind mount the directory is shared, so there's nothing to synchronize. It's literally the same directory.

Thank you, I got the concepts wrong then sorry. So what is really the difference between volume and a bind? When I am using docker compose, I can declare a folder like tmp/:/tmp/ this directly under volumes. Does it get declared as bind mount underneath?

Yes. Both compose and docker run let you define volume mounts and bind mounts using the same syntax which can be confusing. A Docker volume is some disk space managed by docker. This explains the differences.

The error you are getting for mount.TypeVolume is due wrong name of the volume.
Docker expects the Source to be the name of the volume, not an absolute path on the host filesystem.
The error message is specifically complaining about the format of /root/tmp/metrics-60-1990068486 being invalid for a volume name.
If you want to use absolute path use mount.TypeBind instead.
Docker Volume Documentation
